# “Welcome to TeX.SX” without link

Tags: discussion

I saw it several time in the last time, that new users receive a comment `Welcome to TeX.SX` but without linking to the welcome page. Is there a reason for that? It thick it’s nice to just say hello, but guiding new users to the welcome page would be even more helpful …

Comment: i've been one of the commenters who has said "welcome" without a link.  discussion here in meta has fairly often mentioned that at least some people feel that the link is "too much".  perhaps inadvisedly, i reacted with the conclusion that no welcome is impolite, so better a "reduced" one than none at all.  i'm willing to be persuaded otherwise.

Comment: Ok … I missed the discussion about that a link is too much … in my opinion it is not :-)

Comment: I am also one of the users not providing a link. Many users just ask one single question, the welcome page is huge. Seeing the page i imagine  a comic character looking up an indefinitely high wall not being able to get in. We are enough helpers to deal with missing code-markup, spelling and asking for clarification. If the user stays and asks more questions, the OP will notice how the site works. Same for helpers.

Comment: I'm also one of the (sometimes) no linkers. Many times the link seems a bit passive-agressive. And sometimes people add the link even on perfect MWE questions, which then makes the user confused.

Comment: It feels like not a welcome page but a customs controller reading you the visa application. Hence I basically started punching it in manually without the link.

Comment: @percusse: Good point :-)

Comment: I often omit the link in cases where I think that the question does not need any  improvement. Linking to the welcome page is not necessary then, but I still want to welcome the new user. Also, for questions that do need improvement, I often feel that it is better to hint to the specific problems than just to add a link to a page with lots of general information.